# Texturing - how do they make it realistic but specific?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Blender beginner here. I have a question related to texturing, but not how to texture and that kinda stuff. All I want to know is, how do you make the textures? By that I don't mean taking pictures, I mean more how do they make very complicated things, into a texture that fits? Sorry if this is confusing.

An example: a fox. I saw a model where the texture itself had realistic fur (attached the texture that I'm referring to as an image). I'm just wondering how do they do that? Since the model itself was quite realistic, and it doesn't look like they could just find an image on google and fit it.

[image: fox texture]

Another example: buildings with unique textures. Like, a fantasy - more unique - special, version of some sort of already existing material (marble, etc). I do not understand how they make the texture? Like, I don't need an advanced explanation, but it would help if someone could at least try to explain it.

Sorry if this is confusing, I have never posted a question before. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a fur texture in *Texture Paint* mode, with a *Draw/Stencil* brush (unwrap your object with the *Smart UV Project* option, give it an *Image Texture* with an image that you're going to paint on). Make sure that the *Blend* is set to *Mix* with a white color, you can also choose *Hue* and choose a color to give your texture some coloration. When you've painted the whole object, you can whiten or darken some parts with a simple *Draw* brush, choose a white or dark color and *Blend > Lighten* or *Darken*.

[image]